# Understanding the Honeycomb Conjecture

Tags: geometry, limits, area

I was reading about the Honeycomb Conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeycomb_conjecture) , which states that the ratio of the perimeter to area is minimized by using hexagon packings is optimized using hexagon tilings:

[image]

Thomas Hales was able to prove that if you were to draw a circle and start to fill up this circle with some pattern (e.g. uniform hexagons, irregular polygons) -  no matter for what pattern you choose, as the radius of the circle increases to infinity, the perimeter/area ratio will be minimal  (fourth root of 12) for a hexagonal pattern.

[image]

Just to clarify - is this proof able to guarantee that for all the infinite possible tailings that can exist (e.g. irregular tilings), the perimeter/area ratio of all these infinite tailings will necessarily be greater than the perimeter/area ratio of hexagon tilings?

- Have I understood this correctly?

Thank you!